# Send Email To Related Contact of Account When Opportunity Close

Tags: email, visual-workflow

In Flow Builder, I would like to send an email to a related Contact's email addy of the Account associated with the Opportunity.

I created a record-triggered flow that initiates when an Opportunity stage changes to Closed Won.

1. I added an action and filtered by Type-email and selected my email alert for the opp object
2. In the alert, the Recipient Type is Related Contact: Contact
3. The input values for the Record Id is {!$Record.Id} for the opp Id

The email is not being sent. This is what I get back when I debug the flow:
Inputs
SObjectRowId = {!$Record.Id} (0068M0000045AahQAE)
Outputs
None.

How do I send the email to the related Contact?

Comment: Are you able to get solution for this. I am having trouble when I choose Related contact email in the email alert.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing it correctly.  Have you confirmed that your related Contact has the Email field filled out correctly?  If you are in a Sandbox environment, have you checked Setup -> Email -> Deliverability = All email?  Have you tried Setup -> Email -> Test Deliverability?

[image: Flow]
[image: Entry Criteria]
[image: Email Alert]

Comment: Yes, the settings are correct. The action email works in a different flow for a Case object. In the Case flow, there's a Get Record, Assignment, and Create Record elements before the Action email. In my Opp flow, there are no elements in front of it. Does this matter?

Comment: When I change the recipient to anything other than Related Contact, the email is sent. When I switch it back to Related Contact, I get this error:  
Probably Limit Exceeded or 0 recipients Error ID: 530586390-101979 (892677452)

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with the email alert then. More precisely, either the contact or the email. Is the opportunity attached to the contact or the account?

Comment: Yes, the Account has Related Contacts and Opportunities related lists on the Account record page. I want the email to go to the Contacts on the Account. I'm looking into creating an email field on the Opportunity to see if I can do a field update and drill down to reference the Contact email field.