# Schedule Flow to send an Email to the contacts' emails of account in lightning

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, email-alert

Let's say in Salesforce lightning I want to setup an automation email to all contacts of an Account, on a custom date field that is in "Account"

I know that I need to create a classic email template, an email alert, and daily-repeated flow to send it out. Right now I created a Classic Email Template.

My question would be when I create an Email Alert, should I select object "Account" ?
and what would be the recipients type I should select?

I searched for a while and cant get the answer, my setup would be similar to this: [Send Email To Related Contact of Account When Opportunity Close](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383989/send-email-to-related-contact-of-account-when-opportunity-close)
But that case is regarding to "Opportunity" so it is not useful in my case.

If anyone knows some tutorial page for this I would appreciate it as well.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards,
K

---

20230621 Update.

Here is my current setting:

**Flow**
Schedule Triggered Flow 
Start Date: 06/19/2023
Start Time: 12:00:00
Frequency: Daily

Choose object and Filter Condition:
"Account"
Condition: (checkbox field, when senddate match today) Sendtoday = True

node 1: New Get Records-
Object:Contact
Condition: AccountID equals {!$Record.Id}

node 2: Loop
Collection Variable: {!get_Contact}

node 3: Action-
(Email Alert that set)
Record ID: {!loop.id}

Answer (score 0):

RecipientType for Email Alerts has to resolve to

- A field on the target object of type Email
- A related record of the target object using a standard lookup field to User, Lead, or Contact (as those standard objects have OOTB Email fields)

  - e.g. `Opportunity.ContactId`, `Task.WhoId`, `Case.ContactId`
- OwnerId of the target object (this resolves to the User.Email field at runtime)
- Some special cases for groups, roles, teams (members of whom are users who have `User.Email` field values)

The target object of the Email Alert is used to scope the available merge fields. If using VF email templates, it maps to the `relatedToType`.

In your example, the Email Alert target object should be Contact and the recipientType would the `Email Field: Email`. If you need merge fields from the parent Account, [there are limitations on using cross-object merge fields](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdifOUAR/cross-object-merge-fields-in-email-template) and you may need to create formula fields on Contact for use in the template

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I select "Contact" as target object. It got a error message that "given sobject does not match type for alert: Contact".     I use a schedule trigger flow, repeat daily, object is "Account", condition is "If Orderdate = today"

Comment: I mean "LastOrderDate", which is a custom formula date field in "Account"

Comment: please use [edit] on your OP and show your configuration for the Flow Email Action - the Email Action `RecordId` has to be of the same type as the Email Alert target object

Comment: Note that Summer 23 allows use of email templates in Send Email action which eliminates reliance on Email Alerts

Comment: I updated my flow setting  @cropredy  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: ok, looks like you are assuming your Flow email alert has a target object type `Contact` - Please use [edit] and expose your email alert config